# Solr real time get - How to search in real time just with filter

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to use the real time get in SOLR.
In the documentation in all the examples, to get docs in real time I have to use the ID. 
Is it possible to use real time search just with filter?

this is the example in the documentation:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/get?id=mydoc&id=IW-
02&fq=name:realtime-get

{"response":
  {"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":
    [ { "id":"mydoc",
        "name":"realtime-get test!",
        "_version_":1487137811571146752}
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want something like that :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/get?fq=name:realtime-get
{"response":
  {"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":
    [ { "id":"mydoc",
        "name":"realtime-get test!",
        "_version_":1487137811571146752}
    ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that.

Real time get DOES have special requirements, specially that you must do the lookup ONLY by unique-key.

Even if you can add fqs, those are optional, but no enough, you cannot just skip the 'id' (or 'ids') param where you give the unique-key(s)

Answer (score 0):

Your last example uses the filter query as a single query, which just assumes that you don't want any scoring. For the query part you can use `*:*` which is a special shortcut for returning all documents, i.e. `q=*:*&fq=name=realtime-get`.

If you want scoring to be applied, you can just use the filter as your query, `q=name:realtime-get`.

There is nothing special about "real time search" when querying; only in that you do soft commits instead of hard commits (which means that data will be lost if a power failure occurs before the hard commit takes place, as the soft commit is only available in memory).